# Hadoop 0.20.203.0-RC1 reduce stuck at 0%

Tags: apache, hadoop, giraph

I am following this guide below to install Apache Giraph.
http://giraph.apache.org/quick_start.html

I have followed all the steps correctly but when I try to run the wordcount example given in the link, the program gets stuck at

```
16/08/13 14:49:29 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
16/08/13 14:49:30 INFO mapred.JobClient: Running job: job_201608131448_0001
16/08/13 14:49:31 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 0% reduce 0%
16/08/13 14:49:45 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 0%
```

The reduce job doesn't start. How can I fix this?

Comment: Umm... That version of Hadoop is 5 years old

Comment: But that's what Apache Giraph suggests to install in its Quick Start guide!

Comment: I see that. I'm not sure why, though. I don't think that uses Mapreduce2 or YARN, so you could go check the task tracker / job tracker logs for why the job doesn't start

Comment: The quick start guide of Giraph need an update. That version of Hadoop if too old as @Kakaji already say. Try with a modern hadoop version and see if the problem persists. And i'm using Giraph 1.1.0  with hadoop 2.4.0, for example.

Comment: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GIRAPH-1106